# Путь к таблице в ключевом слове from

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Поясните, что означает путь в ключевом слове `from information_schema.tables`? Мне не совсем понятное объяснение, которое дается в учебнике. Это специальный путь доступа, который используется для получения метаданных о базах данных, развернутых в системе. В pl/sql я просто после from указывал в качестве источника данных название таблицы, а тут еще указывается. Назревает вопрос, почему одна БД может содержать несколько схем? В оракле иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Такое имя соответствует общепринятому именованию объектов базы данных: <каталог>.<схема>.<объект>. Одна БД конечно может содержать несколько схем. Имя схемы в T-SQL запросе может быть опущено, в таком случае сервер подставляет имя по умолчанию. Cхема по умолчанию задается  в свойствах имени входа